# Multiple select field only posting first selected value in JSP form

Tags: forms, jsp

In a Spring MVC app using JSP, I have a dynamic form generated via JSTL foreach loop that adds a multiple select field to a form with each iteration:

In my JSP file...

```
<c:forEach items="${myInputList}" var="myInput" varStatus="varstatus">
...
<select multiple="multiple" name="myInputList[${varstatus.index}].optionList">
    <option value="First">First</option>
    <option value="Second">Second</option>
    <option value="Third">Third</option>n
</select>
...
</c:forEach>
```

In the DTO...

```
private String[] optionList;
```

When I select "Second" and "Third" and submit the form, the POST only contains...

```
myInputList[(index value)].optionList=Second
```

The standard advice of postfixing `[]` to the select name (PHP-style) fails when it hits the controller trying to fill the DTO in; no `[]` in the name hits the controller without issues, but the only item in the optionList array is the first value as posted.

Also, originally as a non-multiple select input mapped to a basic, non-array String, this control was working fine.  I'm only attempting to update a single select into a multi-select.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this helps anyone down the road...

The issue I experienced came from inheriting a save method from a parent widget that was only posting form values from the `value` attribute of the form inputs. In the case of multi-select boxes, only the first option selected is in the `value` attribute, while all the selected options are in the `selectedOptions` attribute. I re-worked that save logic to first check `selectedOptions`, otherwise use `value`.